Correct way to send AntiForgeryToken through AJAX request
I've been trying to send the AntiForgeryToken through AJAX request in an ASP.NET Core MVC (area based) Razor view; however, I am definitely missing something to send in the POST request. I read through several documentations and StackO. answers, but all of them are missing something common that I found on this MS documentation: Preventing Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Attacks in ASP.NET MVC Application. I looked at this StackO. question and the replies, and the common difference is that the MS documentation sends both the cookie and form (hidden element) token but I get an error message saying AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken) does not exist in the current context.
I also found this and thought could be really helpful but don't know how to implement into the view.
This SO question is the same as my question, only difference being I want to still use the normal (and non-customized) [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute.
I want to know and learn the right and most secure way to send both the cookie and form antiforgery tokens through ajax post requests while using the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute. Additionally, if there are any flaws or security or usage issues in the code, please do correct me! Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!
Here's my code in the MVC view:
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Kiosk";
}
@model ...
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Kiosk"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery

<h1>Check-in Kiosk</h1>
<title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>

<h2>Follow the instructions below.</h2>

<p id="instructions" style="color: green;">
    Slide your ID card into the card-holder and wait for further instructions.
</p>

<div id="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post" onsubmit="getData()">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger pb-2" id="errors"></div>
            
            <div class="form-floating pb-2">
                <input asp-for="ScannedCode" class="form-control" id="scancode"/>
                <label asp-for="ScannedCode"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="ScannedCode" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-floating pb-2">
                <input asp-for="Number" class="form-control" id="number"/>
                <label asp-for="Number"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Number" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group pt-4">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

    function getFormToken() {
        let token = $('input[name="`__RequestVerificationToken`"]').val();
        return token;
    }

    @functions {
        public string TokenHeaderValue()
        {
            string cookieToken, formToken;
            AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
            return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;
        }
    }

    function getData() {
        let scannedCode = document.getElementById("scancode").innerText;
        let number = document.getElementById("number").innerText;

        sendData(scannedCode, number);
    }

    function sendData(ScannedCode, Number) {
        let realdata = { 
            ScannedCode: ScannedCode;
            Number: Number;
        };
        
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("Index", "Kiosk")",
                data: realdata,
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: 'RequestVerificationToken': '@TokenHeaderValue()',
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.success == true) {
                        document.getElementById("id").hidden;
                        document.getElementById("instructions").innerText = response.message;


                        setTimeout(function () {
                            location.reload();
                        }, response.seconds);
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById("instructions").innerText = response.message;


                        setTimeout(function () {
                            location.reload();
                        }, response.seconds);
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
</script>

Here's the method simply decorated with the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute:
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Index([Bind("ScannedCode,Number")] CodeModel input) {
//Implementation not shown
}


You can use below code
let token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

to get token, here is my test result and test code.
Test Result


KioskController.cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MVCWebApplication.Models;

namespace MVCWebApplication.Controllers;

public class KioskController  : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<KioskController> _logger;

    public KioskController (ILogger<KioskController > logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Index([Bind("ScannedCode,Number")] TestModel input)
    {
        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Data received successfully", seconds = 3 });
    }
}

TestModel.cs
namespace MVCWebApplication.Models
{
   public class TestModel
    {
        public string? ScannedCode { get; set; }
        public string? Number { get; set; }
    }
}

/Kiosk/Index.cshtml
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Kiosk";
}
@model MVCWebApplication.Models.TestModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Kiosk", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "kioskForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-floating pb-2">
        <input asp-for="ScannedCode" class="form-control" id="scancode"/>
        <label asp-for="ScannedCode"></label>
        <span asp-validation-for="ScannedCode" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-floating pb-2">
        <input asp-for="Number" class="form-control" id="number"/>
        <label asp-for="Number"></label>
        <span asp-validation-for="Number" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group pt-4">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getData()">Submit</button>
    </div>
}

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function getData() {
        let scannedCode = $('#scancode').val();
        let number = $('#number').val();

        sendData(scannedCode, number);
    }

    function sendData(scannedCode, number) {
        let realdata = { 
            ScannedCode: scannedCode,
            Number: number
        };

        let token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("Index", "Kiosk")",
            data: realdata,
            headers: {
                "RequestVerificationToken": token
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    $('#instructions').text(response.message);

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        location.reload();
                    }, response.seconds * 1000);
                } else {
                    $('#instructions').text(response.message);
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.error(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<h1>Check-in Kiosk</h1>
<p id="instructions" style="color: green;">
    Slide your ID card into the card-holder and wait for further instructions.
</p>


Sorry for the late reply! Thank you so much for checking in. I tried the solution you gave, and it worked! The only thing I want to understand is this: How is the cookie's forgery token sent to the server using ajax? I mean doesn't the server expect two forgery tokens: One stored in the cookie, and one from the embedded value using @Html.AntiForgeryToken()?
